# Make node.js run on codetasty

Tags: node.js

I am coding on codetasty and wanting to run a nodejs file that works on localhost. I am using the sandbox on codetasty so the link is similar to `https://'s.codetasty.com'/My username/mysandbox/project/`.

```
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");
```

When I direct to my index.html file `https://'s.codetasty.com'/My username/mysandbox/project/client/index.html` only the hmtl "runs" but none of the nodejs is running (on local host you would just do node 'filename'.js in console)

Answer (score 1):

Node (and other server-side projects) don't work on Sandbox workspaces.
Sandbox workspaces are only for front-end coding.